# Java 8 Stream/Collectors map key with Collectors.counting()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to get map of array value frequencies keyed by frequency.
I am able to get opposite - map keyed by value. Tried switching arguments, but `grouping by` does not accept `Collector` as first argument.

Another question, how can I change `Map` implementation to `LinkedHashMap` to preserve ordering by array element (in case of map keyed by values)?

```
  int [] arr = {1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 2, 9, 2, 1};

            Map<Integer, Long> collect = Arrays
                    .stream(arr)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

result is  `{1=4, 2=4, 3=3, 4=3, 5=2, 9=2}`
   what I am looking for is
              `{4=1, 3=[4, 3] , 2=[5, 9] ... }` which means there are 4 occurrences of 1 , 3 occurrences of 4 , 2 occurrences of 5 and 9.

My goal is to get Map with frequency as a Key, and values as List of array elements. For key conflict , add another value to the list of values.

Comment: The "opposite mapping" in your example maps 4 both to 1 and to 2. And as you already know, a key can be mapped only to one value because if you'll try to enter the same key again the value will be overridden. So I'm not clear about what you're trying to accomplish. Try explaining what your goal is, not "how" you're failing to achieve it (also known as the xy problem).

Comment: You can't have both `2=5` and `2=9`.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution is to first create the mapping value -> frequency and then collect it into another map where you do the grouping by the frequency.

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> collect = 
    Arrays.stream(arr)
          .boxed()
          .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(identity(), counting()),
                                     m -> m.entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())))));
```

Maybe a clearer way (not a one liner) is to start from your `collect` map and use `forEach` combined with `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> result = new HashMap<>();
collect.forEach((value, freq) -> result.computeIfAbsent(freq, u -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value));
```

Comment: elegant with `collectingAndThen` +1.

Comment: @Alexis C. Thank you! it works, but can we preserve ordering of array elements (not be ordered by keys, but ordered by array elements instead). I think LinkedHashMap will do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question to test the Stream APIs because most of questions stop at the first group by: group by elements. This question continues the second group by and it's pretty reasonable to me. Here are a few of my thoughts. First, let's try to implement it by the transitional for-loop, (although it's not what the OP wants, but I would like to compare different solutions later).

```
Map<Integer, Integer> occursMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // to keep the order
for (int i : arr) {
    occursMap.compute(i, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
}

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> res = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : occursMap.entrySet()) {
    res.computeIfAbsent(entry.getValue(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(entry.getKey());
}
```

Although it's a little long with 6 lines, it's pretty clear. Then let's take a look at the code provided by @Alexis C.

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> res = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()),
                m -> m.entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())))));
```

It's a great solution. The only problem to me it's not easy read. Probably it will take people a few minutes to figure out what's going on after `collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(...`. Personally I would prefer to remove the nested call:

```
res = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())));
```

The problem is there are still a few totally unnecessary boilerplate codes which cover up the intention of the code. There is a very useful Java 8 library can help us to reduce boilerplate codes: [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
res = EntryStream.of(
               IntStreamEx.of(arr).boxed().groupingBy(Function.identity(), () -> new LinkedHashMap<>(), counting())
        ).invert().grouping();
```

Less boilerplate codes and clearer. But there is still one problem: it's not in a perfect chain. `EntryStream.of(` is too far from its call. There is a fork [StreamEx-0.8.7](https://github.com/landawn/streamex) and I made a few changes:

```
res = StreamEx.of(arr).groupByToEntry(Fn.identity(), Fn.countingInt(), LinkedHashMap::new)
        .inversed().groupTo();
```

Zero boilerplate codes, perfect chain. the code tells and just tells what you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Boring solution without streams

Guava comes with a `Multiset` and `Multimap` implementation that you can use like this to get the same behaviour:

```
Multiset<Integer> set = HashMultiset.create();
for (int i : array) {
   set.add(i);
}

Multimap<Integer, Integer> byFrequency = HashMultimap.create();
for (Integer key : set.keySet()) {
    byFrequency.put(set.count(key), key);
}

Collection<Integer> allKeysWithFreqOfFive = byFrequency.get(5);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in Java Stream solution.

Comment: @joe.d yeah that's not that easy because there is no `MultiMap` collector since that is outside of the SDK and the merging function in `Collectors.toMap()` is not powerful enough to achieve what you want.

Comment: @joe.d AlexisC just beat me to it ;-)